# Why do unwanted lines appear in my plot when saved as an .svg but not .png

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

# Assuming dataset is already defined
dataset2 = #redacted 

# Set up the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))

# Plot the histogram with weights for relative frequencies
weights2 = np.ones_like(dataset2['Angle']) / len(dataset2['Area'])
plt.hist(dataset2['Angle'], bins=15, weights=weights2, color='Black', linewidth=2, label='Virtual')

# Set labels and title with larger font size
plt.xlabel("In-plane ($x_1$-$x_2$) angle range (°)", fontsize=14)

plt.ylabel("Probability", fontsize=14)

# Set x-axis limit
plt.xlim(-90, 90)

# Increase the size of tick labels
plt.xticks(fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)

# Convert y-axis ticks to percentages for the second plot
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:.0%}'.format(y)))

# Add text box in the upper-right corner
a_11_value = 0.58
text_box_content = f'$a_{{11}} = {a_11_value:.2f}$'

plt.text(0.95, 0.95, text_box_content, transform=plt.gca().transAxes,
         verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='right', fontsize=16,
         bbox=dict(facecolor='white', alpha=0.8, edgecolor='black'))

# Specify the folder to save the plots
save_folder = r'savelink 

# Save the combined plot as an SVG and PNG file
plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_folder, 'angledistribution_plots.svg'))
plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_folder, 'angledistribution_plots.png'), dpi=00)


# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

When I save as a svg file I get unwanted white lines on the histogram but this is not a problem with the png?

I expected to have both .svg and .png files to look the same as in there should be no gradient like lines dividing the histogram bins but, they do not.

[weirdlines in.svg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCrMk.png)`

Comment: Hi there @MCC, I think thats because svg files render the charts with verctor graphics making the white lines visible. Try doing this if it helps: `plt.hist(dataset2['Angle'], bins=15, weights=weights2, color='Black', linewidth=2,edgecolor='black', label='Virtual')`

Comment: You could also try passing `histtype='stepfilled'` in your call to `hist`.

Comment: Should I make this as the answer so that this question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because SVG files render the charts with vector graphics making the white lines visible.
Make these changes:

```
plt.hist(dataset2['Angle'], bins=15, weights=weights2, color='Black', linewidth=2,edgecolor='black', label='Virtual')
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as the reason why you see lines in the SVG but not in the PNG, this has to do with the fact that PNGs are raster graphics while SVGs are vector graphics. As you may know, The SVG image is mathematically computed using data inside the file and is an "exact" representation of your figure, while the PNG is a rasterization of that exact representation (can be thought of as a visual approximation of the true figure using a 2D array of discrete pixels). Both the PNG and the SVG could have very minor differences depending on which backend was used to generate them and more importantly which program you use to view them. For example, if I open your image that you posted and zoom out enough, almost all of the lines disappear completely for me. Check to see if the lines are there when using the SVG in its final destination (in a PowerPoint, on a website, etc). Otherwise, try setting your `linewidth` to 0.